# CMake ошибка в CLion

Tags: c++, c, отладка, cmake, cygwin

Всем привет.

В CLion при попытке использовать Cygwin возникает ошибка такого рода:

```
C:\Users\DavidOS\.CLion2016.3\system\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /cygdrive/c/Users/DavidOS/CLionProjects/FooBar
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- broken
CMake Error at /cygdrive/c/Users/DavidOS/.CLion2016.3/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.6.3/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "/usr/bin/cc" is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: /cygdrive/c/Users/DavidOS/CLionProjects/FooBar/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make.exe" "cmTC_1ceee/fast"

  /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ceee.dir/build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_1ceee.dir/build

  make[1]: Entering directory
  '/cygdrive/c/Users/DavidOS/CLionProjects/FooBar/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


        0 [main] make 9860 child_info_fork::abort: C:\cygwin64\bin\cygiconv-2.dll: Loaded to different address: parent(0x600000) != child(0xCD0000)

  make[1]: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable

  make[1]: Leaving directory
  '/cygdrive/c/Users/DavidOS/CLionProjects/FooBar/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


  make: *** [Makefile:126: cmTC_1ceee/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cygdrive/c/Users/DavidOS/CLionProjects/FooBar/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/cygdrive/c/Users/DavidOS/CLionProjects/FooBar/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Хотя всё вроде как установлено правильно и никаких ошибок в toolchain нет

[image: toolcahin]

В Path Cygwin тоже есть: `C:\cygwin64\bin`
В чём может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема не имеет отношения к CLion. Вероятно произошёл неудачный апдейт/установка cygwin. Требуется повторный запуск [rebaseall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125842/what-does-rebaseall-in-cygwin-do). Конфликты при загрузке динамических библиотек.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло! Для тех, кто не поймёт, нужнь запустить `ash /usr/bin/rebaseall` из папки bin директории cygwin от имени администратора